# How to use same value for AppRoles and oauth2Permissions with different Description and Display name?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

My Azure AD application expose scope `Roles.ReadWrite.All`**(Delegated permission)**. Now I want to use machine to machine communication, So I need to expose Application Permission. From the official documentation [How to: Add app roles in your application and receive them in the token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps), I have created a `AppRoles`. Now I can give another application `Application permission` to the application.

But the issue is, I want to use the same value for `Application Permission` and `Delegated Permission`, As Microsoft is already doing this with their `Microsoft Graph` application's `AccessReview.Read.All` permission. But when I want to create `appRoles`, it shows an error -

```
Failed to update Backend API application. Error detail: It contains duplicate value. Please Provide unique value. []
```

I can only create same permission value if I keep the **id**, **description** and **display name** same for both `appRoles`  and `oauth2Permissions`. But `Microsoft Graph` is using two different ID but the same `value`!

```
...
"requiredResourceAccess": [
    {
        "resourceAppId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
        "resourceAccess": [
            {
                "id": "ebfcd32b-babb-40f4-a14b-42706e83bd28", // AccessReview.Read.All
                "type": "Scope"
            },
            {
                "id": "d07a8cc0-3d51-4b77-b3b0-32704d1f69fa", // AccessReview.Read.All
                "type": "Role"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "resourceAppId": "96954c3d-fbb4-4899-be79-582b810acb7b",
        "resourceAccess": [
            {
                "id": "fbeb72c6-dfcb-45b6-b83a-db2929314e70",
                "type": "Scope"
            },
            {
                "id": "42b90870-bbe2-46c6-a221-4f8981c559ae", // Roles.ReadWrite.All
                "type": "Scope"
            },
            {
                "id": "42b90870-bbe2-46c6-a221-4f8981c559ae", // Roles.ReadWrite.All
                "type": "Role"
            }
        ]
    }
],
...
```

As it is shown in the above `Manifest` snippet, `Graph API`'s `AccessReview.Read.All` has two different `id` for `Delegated` and `Application` permission, Where my `Roles.ReadWrite.All` has same ID as a result same `Display Name` and `Description`

Comment: It seems that it's the limitation for custom API configuration in manifest. But based on my test, it won't affect your use. For example, if you assign Delegated permission in your client app, and use client_credentials (without user) to get the access token, the Application permission of the same name won't be included. Vice versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid that what you need is not supported currently.

As you have tested, if we use the same value for "AppRoles" and "OAuth2Permission", it will show this error: **It contains duplicate value. Please Provide unique value.**

When we set the same ID for "AppRoles" and "OAuth2Permission", we will be required to set the same value for (**description, adminConsentDescription**),(**displayName, adminConsentDisplayName**),(isEnabled, isEnabled),(origin, origin),(value, value).

In this case, we can say that we get the same object for "AppRoles" and "OAuth2Permission". But it will not affect your use. The access token can return the correct Delegated permission or Application permission.

Answer (score 1):

I dont get it, how the Microsoft has defined same values for their Microsoft Graph app ?

Example  AppRole values is the same as the Scope values

AppRole:

```html
{
                    "allowedMemberTypes": [
                        "Application"
                    ],
                    "description": "Allows the app to read and update user profiles without a signed in user.",
                    "displayName": "Read and write all users' full profiles",
                    "id": "741f803b-c850-494e-b5df-cde7c675a1ca",
                    "isEnabled": true,
                    "origin": "Application",
                    "value": "User.ReadWrite.All"
                },
```

```html
Scope value:
                
                
                {
                    "adminConsentDescription": "Allows the app to read and write the full set of profile properties, reports, and managers of other users in your organization, on behalf of the signed-in user.",
                    "adminConsentDisplayName": "Read and write all users' full profiles",
                    "id": "204e0828-b5ca-4ad8-b9f3-f32a958e7cc4",
                    "isEnabled": true,
                    "type": "Admin",
                    "userConsentDescription": "Allows the app to read and write the full set of profile properties, reports, and managers of other users in your organization, on your behalf.",
                    "userConsentDisplayName": "Read and write all users' full profiles",
                    "value": "User.ReadWrite.All"
                },
```